# Manual derivation of the type of q (specified in the body)

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I don't realize why `q`'s type is `Ord t => [t] -> [a]` and not `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`

```
q [] = []
q (x:xs) = q us ++ q ws
  where us = filter (<=x) xs
        ws = filter (>=x) xs
```

Under which circumstances the input type could differ from the output?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Comment: What happens if you try to sort a list with this implementation?  There's a very good reason why it has that type.  Try executing `q [1, 3, 2]`, can you tell me why you get that output?

Comment: One of the few cases where omitting the signature actually resulted in a helpful hint to the bug, rather than a more confusing error!

Comment: @bheklilr For any input the output is [], that output is because in every step you remove the first element of the input.

Comment: @Seba, correct, I was hoping that if you saw that, it might give you a clue as to what was wrong with your implementation, although leftaroundabout has provided the solution already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under any circumstances, which here implies: the function is never useful.

This is actually a nice example of "theorems for free". Obviously, the type `Ord t => [t] -> [a]` doesn't make much sense, because the only list you can produce of a type `[a]` (you know nothing about `a`!) is the empty list. So this proves that `q` can do only two things:

- Return `[]`
- Not terminate (i.e., `⟂`)

And indeed the former is what happens: in each recursion step, you pop off an element from the input list, but you never actually include any of these elements in the result. So you always end up with `[]`.

If you'd correctly implemented the quicksort, you'd of course bring `x` back between the two sublists, i.e.

```
q (x:xs) = q us ++ [x] ++ q ws
```